# Hero passion pro India Bike is only get started on choke

Tags: motorcycle, cold-start, choke

i am having hero passion pro new model in the morning when i start my bike with kick i have on the choke the bike started without no hesitation but when i pull of the choke after 15 seconds 
and restarted it ,its not restarting with reserve or in an on state since the fuel is full its about 8 litres petrol guys please help i am unable to start my bike with on or reserve its only getting started on
choke and i have read putting on choke and riding is harmful for a bike it takes lot of petrol and not good for an engine 
how it can be restarted with choke as off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the choke ON to start a cold engine. Once it is running, set it to PARTIAL until the engine is warm. Once the engine has been running a few minutes, set the choke to OFF.

Choke helps the engine run rich. This is necessary when the engine is cold. The engine will start easiest with the choke on. The engine will run best when warm with the choke off.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a carburetor engine, and you need to adjust your idle, make a richer air/fuel mix. Your Idle mix is too lean, so you can't start it. When you get it richer, you might need to adjust a throttle.

---

If you have only 1 screw on a carburetor, it'll be a throttle adjustment for idle. Try to start it warm with opened choke and a bit of a increased throttle (1/4 - 1/2 of a handle). If it starts, just turn that one screw in a little. If it starts okay after this, but idles at too high revs, you'll have to go back to lower idle and get used to start with opened throttle.. Unfortunately cheap carbs don't have the best adjustment options...